# how to remove jquery modal form and keep it as simple html form at the bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how to remove this jquery dialog and show it as a simple html form at the bottom of web page when clicked on button. I've a bootstrap table when i click on the add new record button it shows dialog modal but  i want to make it simple html form without pop up

```
$(function () {

    var new_dialog = function (type, row) {
        var dlg = $("#dialog-form").clone();
        var email = dlg.find(("#email")),
            password = dlg.find(("#password"));
        type = type || 'Create';
        var config = {
            autoOpen: true,
            height: 400,
            width: 450,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Create an account": save_data,
                    "Cancel": function () {
                    dlg.dialog("close");
                }
            },
            close: function () {
                dlg.remove();
            }
        };
        if (type === 'Edit') {
            config.title = "Edit User";
            get_data();
            delete(config.buttons['Create an account']);
            config.buttons['Edit account'] = function () {
                row.remove();
                save_data();

            };

        }
        dlg.dialog(config);
```

Comment: remove model class from div.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it works, but try. Set `false` to `modal` property, and add `position` and `top` properties in config;

```
modal: false,
position: 'relative',
top: 0,
```

Or, in html code delete the `class` attribute of the Div with the modal content.